# Store text command containing itemize in a variable

Tags: macros, itemize

The problem is that I have created a variable containing a text with some `itemize` environment. Now, for some reasons, I want to store the content of it in another variable. But it's not working (see the MWE)

**MNWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\coucou{\begin{itemize}
\item  aa
\item bb
\end{itemize}}
\coucou
\def\aa {zz}
\expandafter\xdef\csname persocmd\aa\endcsname{\coucou} %%Not working
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please don't use the `minimal` class. It's not really well designed

Comment: Ok I changed it to  `article`

Comment: You can't use `\def` in an `\edef` or `\xdef`

Comment: For example `\let\anothervariable=\coucou`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make a macro equivalent to another one, use `\let` (with `\global` if you want so):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\def\coucou{\begin{itemize}
  \item  aa
  \item bb
  \end{itemize}}

\coucou

\def\aa{zz}
\expandafter\let\csname persocmd\aa\endcsname\coucou

\persocmdzz
\end{document}
```

If you want a global definition, just add `\global`:

```
\global\expandafter\let\csname persocmd\aa\endcsname\coucou
```

(note that `\global` triggers expansion of the following token, so it will correctly apply to `\let`).

Note that the proposed

```
\expandafter\gdef\csname persocmd\aa\endcsname{\coucou}
```

will change the meaning also of `\persocmdzz` if the definition of `\coucou` changes.

For instance

```
\expandafter\gdef\csname persocmd\aa\endcsname{\coucou}
\def\coucou{foo}
\persocmdzz
```

would print “foo” and not the itemized list.

One might force expansion of `\coucou` with

```
\expandafter\gdef\csname persocmd\aa\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{\coucou}
```

but it's evident that the `\let` method is much easier.

Instead

```
\expandafter\let\csname persocmd\aa\endcsname\coucou
\def\coucou{foo}
\persocmdzz
```

would print the itemized list.